# Would you help me with terms of WHOM and WHO?

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

To whom/who should I address the latter?

Am I right?

In informal writing, you use who.

.....

Moreover, can I use who instead of whom?

Furthermore, which one is formal, for instance, about TOEFL test?

Whom did  you say  you had seen?

He can't remember whom he saw.

Comment: No, *to whom*.  Informally you can use *who*, but then you should leave the preposition "stranded":  *Who should I address the second one to?*

Comment: The admins turned off the answer box, but I can try to answer this as a comment. "who" is the subjective form of the pronoun (used when the pronoun is the subject of a sentence). "whom" is the objective form of the pronoun (used when the pronoun is the object of the sentence or the object of a preposition). Native speakers usually use "who" for both, but sometimes in formal writing they still want you to use "whom". When used as a conjunction, you can only use "whom" when it is objective in both sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Whom is accusative as opposed to who which is nominative.

However many native speakers won't fuss too much over this.